# French Presidential Election 2017: When will the PS announce its candidate + independants

Tags: presidential-election, france

It seems that, thus far, the five main parties that will take part in the french presidential elections are: PS, LR, FN, EM, FI (see source). The PS seems to be the only party that have still not put forward a candidate. Why is this? When will they put one forward?

I was also wondering if it is likely that any other candidate (independent or from another party) will be on the ballot paper and if so who?

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_presidential_election,_2017

Comment: What is it you call "shortlist " ?

Comment: The list on the ballot paper. I have edited my question to reflect this new clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned, their primary of the PS is to be held on the 22 and 29 of january. I would like to clarify some points of your question and source.

FI and EM are not political parties as you would understand it from an anglo saxon perspective. They are "political movements" (*mouvements politiques*, I don't know if it makes a legal difference), and were founded very recently, with the presidential election as main goal. FI was founded on the 10th february of 2016, and its candidate got the support of several parties since (for the *Parti de Gauche* it was no surprise since it was founded by the same person). EM  was founded on the 6 april 2016, and got the support of political figures  (but no party, maybe as a strategic choice).

In case you are wondering why it tends to be like this. There are plenty of parties with a centrist position ( like EM) and with a far left position  (like FI). PS (left), LR (right) and FN (far right) have a more dominant position in their respective political areas.

While EM may have good vote intentions in the last polls, there are bigger and older parties who also have a centrist position (also mentionned in your source, UDI and MoDem). Those may have their own candidate, and are as likely to be considered "main". Especially since the EM candidate has never held any elected office before  (the election will tell us whether it played in his favor or not).

In order to take part in the election, one needs to have the approval of 500 elected officials (France has more than 36 000). You can assume that the candidates/parties who got them in the 2012 election will have them this time. In the result table of your article, overview section, all of the candidates or parties listed were already here (LR was called UMP), except EM. They are very likely to be here again. To these, one may add François Asselineau who had non negligible results in the last regional election and may get those approvals.

Comment: Brilliant answer thanks! Do you think there is any chance for independents such as Mr Taupin to make it to the ballot paper?

Comment: @Thomas Hollis you mean these guys http://reveildelafrance.fr/des-jumeaux-de-22-ans-candidats-a-la-presidentielle-2017/ ? The legal minimum age to be president is 23. And it is the first time I hear about them.

Comment: However, Sylvain Duriff is making a pretty big buzz. If you understand french and need a good laugh, go see him. It is not impossible that 500 town mayors decide to make a little joke.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zCUG5eicBC4 , the number of views is pretty impressive. Here is he annonces his candidacy : https://youtu.be/M03LOESIU_c

Comment: For what it is worth, EM is actually a classic politic party: http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/politique/20160408.OBS8166/exclusif-le-mouvement-de-macron-en-fait-un-parti-politique-tres-classique.html.

Answer (score 1):

The Parti Socialiste primary will be held [22 January 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Socialist_Party_presidential_primary,_2017), with a runoff on 29 January if no candidate gets more than 50% in the first round.

Presumably, the winner will be announced shortly thereafter.